# How do I edit or clear the application list in the Notifications plug?

Tags: settings, notifications

How can I edit or clear the application list in the Notifications plug? Some old uninstalled apps are still in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of apps and their notification settings is held in gsettings at `org.pantheon.desktop.gala.notifications apps`. You can edit this either directly with the `gsettings` command in Terminal or by installing dconf Editor.

There is currently some work being done to handle this automatically in the future. You can track the issue here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-notifications/+bug/1406799